# Dynamically choose whether to return one Observable or another in RxJs

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am looking for the *most elegant way* for the following task. I know there are multiple ways of doing it and multiple ways following more of an *anti-pattern* (which I don't want here, of course: subscription inside a subscription).

## My Setup

```js
export class MyService {

  giveMeTheBest(...): Observable<TheBest> {
    
    const observable1$ = // Fancy request, returning an Observable
    
    const observable2$ = // A request to a different endpoint, also returning and Observable
    
    return // observable1$, if its content (!) matches a criteria.
    // if observable1$ fails to match a criteria, it should pass on observable2$
    
  }
}
```

## What I want to do

I know that I somehow have to look *into the content* of `observable1$` to see, whether it is matching a certain criteria or not.

- if it does: job done and just returning `observable1$`
- if it does NOT: I want to return `observable2$`.

## Questions

1. Do I have to .subscribe to `observable1$` in the service? (to me this feels not right, because I always subscribed only in the components so far)
2. Or is it possible by only using the .pipe() in combination with pipable operators to figure everything out "in the flow"?

Thank you so much!

Comment: `obs1.pipe(mergeMap(value => yourTest(value) ? of(value) : obs2))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basically the job of `switchMap`.
By default, you subscribe to stream 1. If the content does not match what you are trying to achieve, you unsubscribe from it and subscribes to stream2 instead. Until the next emition coming from stream1

```js
observable1$.pipe(switchMap(content => test(content) ? of (content) : observable2$)
```

Comment: The code is correct but your description of `switchMap` sounds flawed. `switchMap` doesn't unsubscribe from its source, it unsubscribes from its (previous) target if the source emits again.

Comment: I think in my use-case it seems to be irrelevant whether I choose "switchMap" or "mergeMap" as supposed by @jonrsharpe. Both seems to be valid. I didn't think about merging or switching beging the action I want do to, but it might be. If it turns out doing the job I come back and leave kudos ;-)